# how do I get dotenv to config properly with javascript es6 "import"?

Tags: javascript

I changed my setup to use es6 modules and trying to get dotenv to work.

my folder structure was like this:

server server.js and config.env

server/db/conn.js

in conn.js

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config({ path: './config'})
```

but i'd like the config.env to be in server/db, not my server root folder. Even though it's not working in the root folder right now anyway.

I read everything saying put the env in the same folder as server, which it is, but I keep getting this back

```
The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"
```

so it's not using my env. I've tried putting conn.js, server.js, config.js all in the same folder and omitting the "path:" part and just doing dotenv.config() but I get the same results.

it was working fine with the previous method of "require" and setting the path, but I'm switching over to es6 module so that doesn't work anymore.

I've read so many posts about this but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't name the env file. When I was using the Require method, I named the file "config.env" and  it was working fine with that method.

With the es6 import method, this doesn't seem to work. None of the docs I read said anything about not naming the file something. So I just named it ".env" and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass full filename to `path` option. (`config.env` not just `config`)

`files in project dir`

```bash
$ ls -a1
main.js
.env
.env.production
<-- truncated -->
```

`.env.production`

```
PORT=8000
NODE_ENV=production
```

`main.js`

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config({ path: './.env.production' })

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV, process.env.PORT)
```

`output`

```
production 8000
```

Comment: Well, I don't have 2 different env files like that.

I just had one, named "config.env"

I tried making the path as you suggested, with the full path, and filename of config.env but it did not work. So I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at!

like this:

dotenv.config({ path: './db/config.env' });

This does not work.

As soon as I renamed the file to just ".env" and removed put that path in there. It worked.